# Bootstrap Popover inside a table

Tags: jquery, ajax, popover

I have an issue to implement bootstrap popover inside a table. Here is a popover code i have took from the web.

```
$('.main-attributes').popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'auto top',
    trigger: 'manual',
    content: function () {

        var H = $('#div_scoreselector');

        return $(H).html();
    }
})
$('.manage-range').on('click', function (e) {
    var ma = $(this).parents('.main-attributes');
    $('.main-attributes').not(ma).popover('hide');
    $(ma).popover('toggle');
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.main-attributes').off('shown.bs.popover').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $('.popover .save').data('context', $this);
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click', '.save', function () {
    var $context = $(this).data('context');
    var fromval = $('.popover #fromvalue').val();
    var toval = $('.popover #tovalue').val();
    $context.siblings('.text-container').text('From: ' + fromval + ' To: ' + toval);
});
```

When i try to use the code of above for a simple popover function, it works. For example:

```
    <div class='hidden' id='div_scoreselector'>
    <div>
        <h5>Are you sure?</h5>
        <div align="center">
            <button class="btn-dark-grey btn">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-red save">Cancel</button>
            <br/>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>


    <div class='main-attributes'>
          <img id='reset' value='reset' src='/img/some_icon.png' width='30' height='30' key='key' class='manage-range' />
    </div>
```

However, when i try to use that code, as a table response from ajax, nothing happen. I can see the icon, but nothing happen when i click on it. Currently, i just expect that popover window will be opened. After that i will implement the rest of the code. Any one know why it doesn't opened (the icon i located inside the `retTable`).

```
function get_af_status() {
    var ex = document.getElementById('status_table');
    if (  $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( ex ) ) {
         var oTable = $('#status_table').dataTable()
         oTable.fnClearTable();
         oTable.fnDraw()
         oTable.fnDestroy();
    }

    $.ajax(
        {
            url : '/status',
            type: "GET",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                theRows = extract_status_data(data)
                $("#status_table tbody").html(theRows)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('error')
            }
        });
    }

function extract_status_data(jsonDataRaw){
    jsonResultSect = jsonDataRaw['result']
    retTable = ""
    retText = "ret text <br/>"
    for( key in jsonResultSect){
        stat = jsonResultSect[key]
        a = stat['a']
        b = stat['b']
        c = stat['c']
        d = stat['d']
        e = stat['e']

        retTable += "<tr><td><div class='main-attributes'><img id='reset_" + key + "' value='reset' src='/img/some_icon.png' width='30' height='30' key='key' class='manage-range' /></div></td><td>" + key +  "</td><td>" + a + "</td><td>" + b + "</td><td>" + c + "</td><td>" + d + "</td><td>" + e + "</td></tr>"

}
    return retTable
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It could well be that it has opened just inside the table. In the browser inspect the code to see if it is open and perhaps change the overflow style of the cell.